# Pandas - Changing column sequence using index value of column stored in a variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe as below:

```
  col_1 col_2 col_3
0    1    3     2
1    3    5     3
2    3    4     3
```

I am trying to have the sequence in which the columns are displayed using the index value of the header.

I have the index value of column stored in a variable called `val`. Set value of `val` = 1

I have tried the below:

```
cols = list(df.columns.values)
cols.pop(cols.index(val))
df = df[[val] + cols]
```

Expected output:

```
  col_2 col_1 col_3
0    3    1     2
1    5    3     3
2    4    3     3
```

I however see the sequence has not changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val = 1
cols = list(df.columns.values)
extracted =cols.pop(val)
cols.insert(0,extracted)
df = df[cols]
```

output

```
 col_2  col_1   col_3
0   3   1   2
1   5   3   3
2   4   3   3
```